# In-app billing remove checking purchased item everytime

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to have in-app billing in my android app,

I get help from Google's TrivialDrive sample.

Every time I open the app it checks for purchased items. But I don't want it to check it every time: I want the purchased items to be cashed in the user's phone so there's no need to check it every time.

(Sometimes the users doesn't have internet access).

Comment: You need to add much more information than this in order to get helped. Very important is to add the code you've got so far, so other users will more easily help you.

Answer (score 0):

Purchased items are cached locally in the Google Play app with In-app billing v3.

The user doesn't need an Internet connection for that, so there's no problem in checking it every time.

> Because the Google Play client now caches In-app Billing information
>   locally on the device, you can use the Version 3 API to query for this
>   information more frequently, for example through a getPurchases call.
>   Unlike with previous versions of the API, many Version 3 API calls
>   will be serviced through cache lookups instead of through a network
>   connection to Google Play, which significantly speeds up the API's
>   response time.

From [In-app billing Version 3's page](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html).